# Fit content inside div bootstrap or css

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have two divs inside another one. One of them contains a buttom that I need to stick to the bottom of the parent div, and another one that will contain a list of persons or a text, the problem is if the text is large, it will go out of the div, and I can't figure it out yet how to solve it. This is the code:

```
          <div class="white container shadow-box-5 fixed-bottom">
            <div class="fluid-container position-relative h-100">
              <div class="flex-wrapper h-100">
                <div class="pt-3">
                  <span>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                    elit. Exercitationem officia odit omnis maiores nesciunt
                    numquam voluptas quo perspiciatis quaerat aperiam
                    tempore excepturi pariatur ducimus, nihil, eveniet iure
                    culpa dicta minus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio optio, pariatur
                    quaerat sunt quam magnam numquam. Quia reiciendis
                    delectus dignissimos totam cum ex repellendus aliquid
                    esse. Dignissimos doloremque suscipit ullam! Lorem ipsum
                    dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
                    fugiat culpa iure quas, vero nesciunt quaerat
                    repellendus dolor dignissimos aspernatur odio harum,
                    sequi, quidem aliquam doloremque repellat quae veritatis
                    magnam.
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="position-absolute w-100 mb-4">
                  <button
                    @click="
                      $router.push({
                        name: 'ECommerce',
                        hash: '#productmonth',
                      })
                    "
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                  >
                    Comparar
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And this is how the div is looking right now.

[image]

Comment: Do you what it to scroll instead?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I want the text to fit inside its div and have a scroll. The text is just a dummy, there will be a list of persons. But I need to fit over the button.

Comment: Can you show your css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally what I needed to do is add an overflow-auto to the div containing the span. It was easiest than I thought.

```
      <div class="white container shadow-box-6 fixed-bottom white-card">
        <div class="fluid-container position-relative h-100">
          <div class="flex-wrapper h-100 pt-4">
            <div class="overflow-auto px-2" style="height: 80%">
              <div
                v-for="(persona, index) in ranking"
                :key="'persona' + index"
                class="persona-container"
              >
                <div v-if="index >= 1">
                  <div
                    class="
                      d-flex
                      align-items-center
                      justify-content-between
                      px-2
                      my-3
                      person-box
                    "
                    :class="
                      persona.id_sharp == user_idSharp
                        ? 'person-back2'
                        : 'person-back1'
                    "
                    :id="
                      persona.id_sharp == user_idSharp ? 'active' : 'inactive'
                    "
                  >
                    <div class="col-1 text-center">
                      <p class="font-Roboto fs-16 my-auto text-gray-400">
                        {{ index + 1 }}
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2 pl-2">
                      <div v-if="persona.prof_picture == null">
                        <img
                          src="@/assets/img/questionmark.png"
                          alt=""
                          class="avatar-3 rounded-circle shadow-box"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div v-else>
                        <img
                          :src="
                            'https://api-dev.embajadores.com.co/' +
                            persona.prof_picture
                          "
                          alt=""
                          class="avatar-3 rounded-circle shadow-box"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col overflow-hidden p-3">
                      <div class="">
                        <p
                          class="
                            font-RobotoBold
                            fs-14
                            text-capitalize text-truncate
                            my-1
                          "
                        >
                          {{ persona.site.name.toLowerCase() }}
                        </p>
                        <p
                          class="
                            font-Roboto
                            fs-14
                            text-capitalize text-truncate
                            my-1
                          "
                          :class="
                            persona.id_sharp == user_idSharp
                              ? 'text-gray-400'
                              : 'text-gray-300'
                          "
                        >
                          {{ persona.name.toLowerCase() }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-2">
                      <div
                        class="shadow-box-2 bor-rounded-xs text-center"
                        style="width: 38px; height: 38px"
                      >
                        <p
                          class="font-RobotoBold fs-16"
                          style="line-height: 38px"
                        >
                          {{
                            Math.round(
                              parseFloat(
                                persona.average
                                  .substring(0, 5)
                                  .replace(",", ".")
                              )
                            )
                          }}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
              class="tag-3 image-container-2 text-center"
              @click="scroll('active')"
            >
              <!-- <p
                class="
                  fs-16
                  font-RobotoBold
                  rounded-circle
                  bg-orange-450
                  h-100
                  line-height-30
                  mx-auto
                  text-white-100
                "
              >
                1
              </p> -->
              <i
                class="
                  icon-flecha-abajo
                  text-white-100
                  bg-orange-450
                  rounded-circle
                  fs-30
                "
              ></i>
            </div>
            <div class="position-absolute w-100 mb-4">
              <button
                @click="
                  $router.push({
                    name: 'CompareLeaders',
                  })
                "
                type="button"
                class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
              >
                Comparar
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Tailwind. Here's what you need. You can also try it out in [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/FSyQLWsxcF).

```html
<section class="bg-red-50 border-red-100 border-8 h-screen p-6">
  <div class="flex flex-col flex-nowrap gap-y-4 h-full">
    <div class="flex-grow overflow-y-auto">
      <p>Friday night. I hate the Wetlands. They're stupid and wet, and there are bugs everywhere, and I think I maced a crane.</p>
      <p class="mt-4">But I did finally get into Dad's pants. Although I had to have the crotch taken in a little bit. Heyyyyy, hermano. I don't appreciate the dry British humor. I never thought I'd miss a hand so much! Get rid of the Seaward.</p>
      <p class="mt-4">Lucille: I'll leave when I'm good and ready. I don't criticize you! And if you're worried about criticism, sometimes a diet is the best defense.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-none">
      <button class="bg-red-500 p-3 rounded text-white w-full">Comparar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="white container shadow-box-5 fixed-bottom">
            <div class="fluid-container position-relative h-100">
              <div class="flex-wrapper h-100">
                <div class="pt-3">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
                    elit. Exercitationem officia odit omnis maiores nesciunt
                    numquam voluptas quo perspiciatis quaerat aperiam
                    tempore excepturi pariatur ducimus, nihil, eveniet iure
                    culpa dicta minus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio optio, pariatur
                    quaerat sunt quam magnam numquam. Quia reiciendis
                    delectus dignissimos totam cum ex repellendus aliquid
                    esse. Dignissimos doloremque suscipit ullam! Lorem ipsum
                    dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi
                    fugiat culpa iure quas, vero nesciunt quaerat
                    repellendus dolor dignissimos aspernatur odio harum,
                    sequi, quidem aliquam doloremque repellat quae veritatis
                    magnam.
                </div>
                <div class="position-absolute w-100 mb-4">
                  <button
                    @click="
                      $router.push({
                        name: 'ECommerce',
                        hash: '#productmonth',
                      })
                    "
                    type="button"
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                  >
                    Comparar
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Try this!

I need the css to help you more.